# class is intervalar 0- 20 regression or NN?

Tags: regression

The class is quantity of children. So at first I thought of a linear regression, but then, since it will never predict extreme values, but there will be lot's of zeros. Is there any problem of using a regression in this case? 
Also, if I treat the class as nominal I loose information.
What model would you use to predict number of children considering education, income, home characteristics, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your problem clearly. You are talking about regression but i think it's more a classification problem as you are trying to predict classes label for each instance.

For this  case, a simple Random Forest or SVM classifiers should do the work. If you want to go further, you should also perform some features selections.

But if you absolutly want to do a regression, i'd suggest to choose logistic regression over linear regression.